# Django авторизация: A server error occurred. Please contact the administrator

Tags: python, авторизация, django

Всем привет!

Недавно начал изучать Django и столкнулся с проблемой при авторизации.
Сначала при отправке формы выдавало ошибку “CSRF token missing or incorrect”. Поиски в интернете подсказал что нужно прописать

```
django.middleware.csrf.CsrfResponseMiddleware
```

. После добавления этой строчки в settyngs.py данные с формы принялись, но на самом сайте начало выдавать “A server error occurred. Please contact the administrator.”, а родной сервер говорит `“ImproperlyConfigured: Module ”django.middleware.csrf“ does not define a ”CsrfMiddleware“ attribute/class”.`

Если закоментить все связаное с “django.middleware.csrf” то отображать начинает все нормально.

Подскажи пожалуйста в чем я намудрил и как это решается.

p.s. версия 1.6

Comment: Где-то не там вы искали https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#middleware-classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выложите settings.py

В любом случае, стандартного списка мидлварь хватает.

Добавьте в кортеж `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` мидлварь '`django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware`', если таковой отсутствует.
Больше ничего не требуется.

Ну и, в целом, отправляете ли вы в форме `{% csrf_token %}` ?

Comment: Спасибо. Заработало. Удалил все связанное с csrf кроме того что Вы сказали ну и токен на форму добавил и все заработало.
Еще раз спасибо!